# Why scanf cannot read my input?

Tags: c, scanf

I would like use `scanf()` to read the following table:

```
Q 1 3
U 2 6
Q 2 5
U 4 8
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int *a;
    int i, j;

    a = (int *) malloc(4 * 3 *sizeof(int));

    printf("input:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           scanf("%d", a + 3 * i + j);
        }
    }

    printf("output:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           printf("%d  ", a[3*i+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

[image]

However, when I input the first line `Q 1 3`, this program end. I don't know why?

Comment: Declare `a` as `char` pointer and use `scanf(" %c", a + 3 * i + j);`. A space before `%c` is intentional. Also change `printf("%d  ", a[3*i+j]);` to `printf("%c  ", a[3*i+j]);`. (I assume that only one digit numbers are used in input).

Comment: Please don't post animated GIFs. It would be best if you didn't post an image at all, just copy/paste the transcript into the question and mark it as code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you provided a non-numeric input to your program that wants to read a number with `%d`. Since `Q` is *not* a number, `scanf` fails.

However, your program is not paying attention to the return value of `scanf`, and keeps calling it in the failed state. The program thinks that it is getting some data, while in fact it does not.

To fix this, change the code to pass `%c` or `%s` when it reads the non-numeric character, check the return value of `scanf`, and get rid of invalid input when `scanf` fails.

When you call `scanf`, it returns how many values corresponding to `%` specifiers it has provided. Here is how to check the return value of `scanf`:

```
if (scanf("%d", a + 3 * i + j) == 1) {
    ...                   // The input is valid
} else {
    fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]"); // Ignore to end of line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the letter Q is not a number, so `scanf` will fail and leave the input buffer untouched. So the next iteration `scanf` will see the same Q and again fail, and so on and on and on...

That will mean nothing is actually read into the memory you allocate, and you print out the uninitialized memory, leading to *undefined behavior*.

One possible way to solve your problem might be to read *lines* instead (using e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)), and then use `sscanf` to parse the whole line in one go. Perhaps something like

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    char buffer[64];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
        char c;  // The character
        int a, b;  // The integer values
        sscanf(buffer, "%c %d %d", &c, &a, &b);
        a[3 * i + 0] = c;
        a[3 * i + 1] = a;
        a[3 * i + 2] = b;
    }
}
```

I also recommend you actually initialize the memory you allocate, especially if you're not going to use parts of it but still print it out.

Comment: So I would like to know how to deal with it?

Comment: @ShutaoTang [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns the number of items successfully matched...

Answer (score 0):

Either use `scanf()` with int variable with proper ASCII value or use `scanf()` with char variable for character but print with %c in both cases. ASCII code for *Q* is 81 and for *U* it is 85.